# Attaching an event listener to a specific input range value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Having an html input range values from 0 - 100 , how can i attach an event listener to specific values?
For example, when reaching values of 45, change the background color.

```
<input id="myrange" type="range" min="0" max="100" />
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/59ah9mhp/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery

```js
$("#myRange").change(onSlideChange);

function onSlideChange(){
 var val = $("#myRange").val();
 if(val==45){
   $("#result").text("It's 45");
 }else{
   $("#result").text("It's another value ("+val+")");
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" id="myRange" value="90">
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Html

```
<input type="range" id="myRange" value="90"  onchange="showVal(this.value)">
```

Js

```
function showVal(val){
 if(val==45){
   alert("It's 45");
 }else{
   alert("It's "+val);
 }
}
```

Here, Instead of showing alert, you can do whatever you want :)

Comment: For a jQuery question, inline event handlers should be avoided. (yes, I realise you went for plain JS)